# Select value from combobox based on the value from other combobox

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 combo boxes and I want to select a value from 1st combo box and then based on that value I have to get a particular value from second combobox.

In my case if I am selecting **abc** then the value should be **not yet** and if I select **xyz** it should be **no**

How can I do this?

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2">def</option>
    <option value="3">xyz</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
    <option value="a">yes</option>
    <option value="b">no</option>
    <option value="c">not yet</option>              
</select>
```

Comment: I completely fail to understand the relationship between `abc` and `not yet`.

Comment: Its just an example. if I select abc from first combobox the other combobox should automatically show not yet from second combo box.

Comment: You haven't explained how the first option in one select is related to the third option in another. It's apparently critical to your question.

Comment: As I said its an example I want to show not yet when I select the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `onchange` event:

```
document.getElementById("first").onchange = function() {
    var value = this.value; //value of first select
    var text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; //text of chosen element

    if (text == "abc") {
        //select second dropdown
    } else if () {
        //more logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use a map for the datas like this way,

```
var dataHolder = {
    "0" : "",
    "1" : "abc",
    "2" : "def",
    "3" : "xyz"
};
```

be sure that keys of the dataHolder are the values of the first select and values of the dataHolder are their corresponding values of second select.

```
document.getElementById("first").onchange = function() {

    var firstSelectValue = this.value;
    var secondSelectExpectedValue = dataHolder[firstSelectValue];

    if (secondSelectExpectedValue != null){
        document.getElementById('second').value = secondSelectExpectedValue ;
    }
}
```

Use the idea not the exact code :).